# JavaScript Output and Control Flow errors when comparing two values

Tags: javascript, output, conditional-statements, control-flow

I'm trying to create a program that compares two different values(x, y) and determines if the first is greater, equal, or less than the other. In addition to that it will also detect if a value entered is NaN and output an error statement. The code is below....

```
function getRelationship(x, y) {
    if (x > y) {
        return ">";
    }
    else if (x < y) {
        return "<";
    }
    else if (x == y) {
        return "=";
    }
    else if (isNaN(x)) {
        console.log("Can\'t compare relationships because " + x + " is not a number");
        return x;
    }
    else if (isNaN(y)) {
        console.log("Can\'t compare relationships because " + y + " is not a number");
        return y;
    }
    else if (isNaN(x) && isNaN(y)) {
        console.log("Can\'t compare relationships because " + x + " and " + y + " are not numbers");
        return x, y;
    }
}
```

When I input the following function calls:

```
console.log(getRelationship(1,4));
console.log(getRelationship(1,1));
console.log(getRelationship("that",2));
console.log(getRelationship("this"," something else")); 
console.log(getRelationship(3)); 
console.log(getRelationship("hi"));
console.log(getRelationship(NaN));
console.log(getRelationship(NaN, undefined));
```

I get this back:

```
LOG: '<'
LOG: '='
LOG: 'Can't compare relationships because that is not a number'
LOG: 'that'
LOG: '>'
LOG: 'Can't compare relationships because undefined is not a number'
LOG: undefined
LOG: 'Can't compare relationships because hi is not a number'
LOG: 'hi'
LOG: 'Can't compare relationships because NaN is not a number'
LOG: NaN
LOG: 'Can't compare relationships because NaN is not a number'
LOG: NaN
```

So my questions are how come on the fourth function call in the `Else If` statement with the `&&` operator is not being utilized; how come "this" and "something else" are being compared and how can I change that to utilize the `&&` conditional; and how come I'm getting `NaN` and some of the other strings outputted when all I want are the pre coded `console.log()` outputs?

Answer (score 0):

> how come on the fourth function call in the Else If statement with the && operator is not being utilized?

Because the `if (isNaN(x))` case was tried before it and did match.

> how come "this" and "something else" are being compared?

Well, they're both strings, why wouldn't they be compared?

> and how can I change that

I think you are looking to compare only numbers. In that case, be explicit about that. You could simply cast both operands to numbers (using `Number`), but notice that will work on numeric strings as well. If you don't want that, do a `typeof` check on your operands.

> and how come I'm getting NaN and some of the other strings outputted when all I want are the pre coded console.log() outputs?

Because you `return`ed them, and are `console.log`ging the results of your calls.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Now for the first question do I need to out that else if in front of (isNaN(x))?

As for the last question the reason I returned them was to avoid getting 'undefined' as my output. Any suggestion on how to avoid both the output log and an 'undefined' output?

Comment: Not really, I'd recommend to just ignore the `undefined`s. You could of course `return` your "output message", but for proper error handling you'd better `throw` them.